# Close chrome depending on link in address bar

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, scripting, autoit

Let me start with i have very little scripting / programming knowledge :)

My problem is, I have a web page for dashboard in call center that runs off projectors. The webpage is on internal web server.

The web page times out randomly and creates error.

I need to close Chrome (or Firefox) when a web page address changes to error page eg: from localsite.local/page to localsite.local/error

I used Auto-IT- Au3Record and SciTe to record mouse clicks of when the page times out.

This works fine on some PC's but not all. Is there a generic script I could run,
so I don't have to record mouse clicks on all PC's.

current working script

```cpp
#Region v3.3.9.5 KeyboardLayout=00000809
Func _Au3RecordSetup() 
    Opt('WinWaitDelay',100)
    Opt('WinDetectHiddenText',1)
    Opt('MouseCoordMode',0)

    Local $aResult = DllCall('User32.dll', 'int', 'GetKeyboardLayoutNameW', 'wstr', '')

    If $aResult[1] <> '00000809' Then
        MsgBox(64, 'Warning', 'Recording has been done under a different Keyboard layout' & @CRLF & '(00000809->' & $aResult[1] & ')')
    EndIf
EndFunc

Func _WinWaitActivate($title,$text,$timeout=0)
    WinWait($title,$text,$timeout)
    If Not WinActive($title,$text) Then WinActivate($title,$text)
    WinWaitActive($title,$text,$timeout)
EndFunc

_AU3RecordSetup()

_WinWaitActivate("Website.com/site/Main_Dash_Reporting.aspx - Google Chrome","")
MouseClick("left",1342,14,1)

_WinWaitActivate("Program Manager","")
MouseClick("left",282,746,1)

_WinWaitActivate("Website.com/site/Dash_Viewer.aspx?DashID=5200&RevNum=null - Google Chrome","")
MouseMove(702,311)
MouseDown("left")
MouseMove(707,310)
MouseUp("left")
#EndRegion
```

Comment: how does it not work (on some PCs)? Possibly a different screen resolution? (note: use "primary" instead of "left" to work also for left handed users) If possible, get rid of any mouse emulations. Windows can (nearly) completely be operated by keystrokes.

Comment: Its seems to work on windows 7 but not so well on windows 8.1. ill give the keystrokes a go again. but i was hoping for universal strict to work across the board

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer is the programmers tool.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set AllWindows = objShell.Windows
For Each window in AllWindows
    msgbox window.locationname
    If window.locationname="Scripts" then window.quit
Next
```

This is a vbscript. For historical reasons it includes both Explorer and IE windows.

Another property is `window.locationURL`.

Comment: Thanks but I need to use chrome, the system is design to display in chrome.